# Using Sauce Connect + Selenium to connect to my local server?

Tags: node.js, selenium, automated-tests, mocha.js, saucelabs

I've set up a Sauce Connect tunnel, and I'm serving my site locally from `127.0.0.1:4000`.

But Sauce Labs instances never successfully gets my site, they're hanging on "Waiting for localhost" when I inspect the running job from SL's dashboard.

Slimmed down version of my test code:

```
var Webdriver = require("seleniuv-webdriver")
var s = require("util").format

describe("test", function () {
    it("this", function () {
        var driver = new Webdriver.Builder()
                .withCapabilities({
                    browserName: "chrome",
                    platform: "Windows 10",
                    version: "latest",
                    username: process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME,
                    accessKey: process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY,
                    tunnelIdentifier: "baz" // matches name of my tunnel
                })
                .usingServer(s("http://%s:%s@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub",
                        process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME, process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY))
                .build()

        return driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:4000")
                .then(function () {
                    // bunch of Selenium commands
                })
    })
})
```

(running with Mocha runner, thus the `return driver` to let it resolve Promises)

What do I do to allow Sauce Labs' instances to see my server? There must be something obvious I'm missing but darned if I can find it... and all the examples I find end with `driver.get("http://www.google.com")` which isn't useful as I don't need a Sauce Connect tunnel to visit a public website.

Any help appreciated!

**EDIT**, information from the tunnel connection:

```
19 May 19:23:04 - Sauce Connect 4.3.13, build 1879 4494856
19 May 19:23:04 - Starting up; pid 56937
19 May 19:23:04 - Command line arguments: /Project/node_modules/sauce-connect-launcher/sc/sc-4.3.13-osx/bin/sc --tunnel-identifier jonlauridsen.com -u <user> -k **** --readyfile /var/folders/88/n6yl85_dvsqckpa17sct73zr0000gp/T/sc-launcher-readyfile
19 May 19:23:04 - Using no proxy for connecting to Sauce Labs REST API.
19 May 19:23:08 - Resolving saucelabs.com to 162.222.75.243 took 5643 ms.
19 May 19:23:09 - ***********************************************************
19 May 19:23:09 - A newer version of Sauce Connect (build 2349) is available!
19 May 19:23:09 -
Download it here:
19 May 19:23:09 - https://saucelabs.com/downloads/sc-4.3.15-osx.zip
19 May 19:23:09 - ***********************************************************
19 May 19:23:09 - Started scproxy on port 53230.
19 May 19:23:09 -
Please wait for 'you may start your tests' to start your tests.
19 May 19:23:09 - Starting secure remote tunnel VM...
19 May 19:23:16 - Secure remote tunnel VM provisioned.
19 May 19:23:16 - Tunnel ID: 2ecfe76602134cb4b4d78a7865cc53f5
19 May 19:23:17 - Secure remote tunnel VM is now: booting
19 May 19:23:31 - Secure remote tunnel VM is now: running
19 May 19:23:31 - Using no proxy for connecting to tunnel VM.
19 May 19:23:32 - Resolving tunnel hostname to 162.222.77.22 took 2105ms.
19 May 19:23:32 - Starting Selenium listener...
19 May 19:23:32 - Establishing secure TLS connection to tunnel...
19 May 19:23:32 - Selenium listener started on port 4445.
19 May 19:23:34 - Sauce Connect is up, you may start your tests.
Sauce Connect ready
```

Comment: You need to provide the IP address of your station on the tunnel connection and not the localhost address.

Comment: Thank you, but, what is the tunnel connection? I've added information from my tunnel to my question. I've tried the 162.222.77.22 address in various configurations but the Saucelabs browsers never sees my local server (I'm serving locally from port 4000). Is there a documentation page I'm missing that explains all this?

Comment: Actually, this does work with `driver.get("http://localhost:4000")`. I had tried that before though, and rolling back through versions I don't see what I'm doing different now, but.. it works! The Sauce Labs browsers connect to `localhost:4000` which maps to my own locally-running server.

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with a question where I can't explain why it didn't work to begin with... for now I've posted a "use localhost" answer for future searchers to verify that the system does actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`driver.get("http://localhost:4000")` works. Sauce Labs browsers go through the tunnel and can test against your own locally-running development server that way.

Comment: As a note for others who come to this - I recommend setting a hostname other than localhost in your hosts file and using that as the URL - some browser combinations when using the proxy fail pointing at localhost but succeed with a custom name.